# Need Split the data of my tab delimited file C#

Tags: c#, split

I need to split the text file (tab delimited) in columns and load in SQL Server. The problem is data in the file is not in a same manner there are spaces in columns like this:

```
Name(Single Space)Sex(Multiple Spaces)Designation(Single Space)Salary(Multiple Spaces)
```

I am using following code to split the files but its not according to my need.

```
for (int index = 2; index < allLines.Length; index++)
{
    // split up the data line into its parts, using "|" as separator

    //string[] items = allLines[index].Split(new char[] { '\t' });
    string[] items = allLines[index].Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' });

    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = items[0];
    cmd.Parameters["@GENDER"].Value = items[1];
    cmd.Parameters["@CITY"].Value = items[2];
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this? Is the split working correctly or are values joined together or is there too much extra space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to match words(consecutive sequences of characters), so that you can avoid splitting at all.

Try the following

```
var items = Regex.Matches(allLines,@"\w+").OfType<Match>().Select(mt => mt.Value);
```

[See Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/fG8eO8/3)

Answer (score 1):

There is an overloading method for Split that handle those empty entries.

```
string[] items = allLines[index].Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I used the code you provided but still nothing change.

Comment: Won't this just remove empty entries? And not ones any extra space?

Answer (score 1):

If the `.Split` is working fine but the values you are adding into the query have extra whitespace you can use the [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) method to remove any extra white space. I would use it as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = items[0].Trim();
cmd.Parameters["@GENDER"].Value = items[1].Trim();
cmd.Parameters["@CITY"].Value = items[2].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex replace in order to dedupe double tabs in the data

```
string data = Regex.Replace(input, "\\t+", "\t");
```

The `\t+` will match any occurrence of one or more tabs and replace it with a single tab.